# Preventing HTML character entities in locale files from getting munged by Rails3 xss protection

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3, xss

We're building an app, our first using Rails 3, and we're having to build I18n in from the outset. Being perfectionists, we want real typography to be used in our views: dashes, curled quotes, ellipses et al.

This means in our locales/xx.yml files we have two choices:

1. Use real UTF-8 characters inline.
   Should work, but hard to type, and
   scares me due to the amount of
   software which still does naughty
   things to unicode.
2. Use HTML
   character entities (&#8217;
   &#8212; etc). Easier to type,
   and probably more compatible with
   misbehaving software.

I'd rather take the second option, however the auto-escaping in Rails 3 makes this problematic, as the ampersands in the YAML get auto-converted into character entities themselves, resulting in 'visible' &8217;s in the browser.

Obviously this can be worked around by using `raw` on strings, i.e.:

```
raw t('views.signup.organisation_details')
```

But we're not happy going down the route of globally `raw`-ing every time we `t` something as it leaves us open to making an error and producing an XSS hole.

We could selectively `raw` strings which we know contain character entities, but this would be hard to scale, and just feels wrong - besides, a string which contains an entity in one language may not in another.

Any suggestions on a clever rails-y way to fix this? Or are we doomed to crap typography, xss holes, hours of wasted effort or all thre?

Comment: that's a good question. looking forward to a good answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a [ticket in lighthouse](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2409-activerecord-double-escapes-error_messages_for) for this problem, and the resolution is to append `_html` to the i18n key in the `locales/xx.yml` file and use the `t` alias<sup>**1**</sup> to denote an html_safe string. For example:

```
en:
  hello: "This is a string with an accent: &oacute;"
```

becomes:

```
en:
  hello_html: "This is a string with an accent: &oacute;"
```

And it would create the following output:

> This is a string with an accent: ó

This would prevent you from having to write `raw t('views.signup.organisation_details')` and would result in a cleaner output of: `t('views.signup.organisation_details_html')`. And while exchanging `raw` for `_html` doesn't seem like the greatest of trades, it does make things clear that you're outputting what is assumed to be an html_safe string.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> I've tested the code suggested in the lighthouse ticket. What I found was that you had to specifically use the `t` alias. If you used `I18n.t` or `I18n.translate` the translation didn't treat `_html` as html_safe:

```
I18n.t('hello_html') 
I18n.translate('hello_html') 
# Produces => "This is a string with an accent: &oacute;"

t('hello_html')      
# Produces => "This is a string with an accent: ó"
```

I don't think this is the intended behavior per the [RoR TranslationHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate).

Answer (score 8):

Well. I bookmarked this question yesterday because of the i18n angle, but didn't answer it as I'm a Python person who's never used Rails. I'm still not going to answer it, but given you aren't being overrun by helpful Railsians who could point you at a good way of getting around Rails' innards, here's my perspective nonetheless.

First of all I think it's *great* that you're thinking about the problem from the outset. That's pretty rare. Second, I completely agree that using raw strings or selectively picking strings with entities to give a special treatment to sounds like a brittle, ugly, bug-prone hack.

Now if I understand Rails correctly (I read [this i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)), the YAML files contain the localised string for each language. In this case, I'd strongly recommend to use regular characters in them (in UTF-8). Otherwise, maintaining localizations, or even *reading* through a translation file -- think of languages in non-Latin scripts! -- is going to be hell.

Yeah, it would mean you have to figure out input methods, but the solution is clean and straightforward.

Comment: yup, just place the full UTF-8 encoded characters in the file. Its what the Java guys have been doing since the dinosaurs - look in all their language .properties files and you will see the native encodings.

Comment: In retrospect, I think this is maybe the best solution. I don’t know why I was so averse to it 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I think it isn't a good idea to use use "raw", you could try with yml string like this

```
en:
  hello:
    This generates a text paragraph for HTML. " " à @ ' All this text, which you can find in
    these lines, is being concatenated together to one single text node, and then put
    into the body of the <p> ... </p> tag. ↂↀऊᎣᏍᏮ⁜℺℻⊛⍟⎬⎨⏏♞♝⚫⚬✱✰✭❺❻➣➱➲⬡⬕
```

HTML

```
This generates a text paragraph for HTML. &quot; &quot; à @ ' All this text, which you can find in these lines, is being concatenated together to one single text node, and then put into the body of the &lt;p&gt; ... &lt;/p&gt; tag. ↂↀऊᎣᏍᏮ⁜℺℻⊛⍟⎬⎨⏏♞♝⚫⚬✱✰✭❺❻➣➱➲⬡⬕
```

browser view

```
This generates a text paragraph for HTML. " " à @ ' All this text, which you can find in these lines, is being concatenated together to one single text node, and then put into the body of the <p> ... </p> tag. ↂↀऊᎣᏍᏮ⁜℺℻⊛⍟⎬⎨⏏♞♝⚫⚬✱✰✭❺❻➣➱➲⬡⬕
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna expose to the possibility of a mistake by simple adding .html_safe (through alias_method_chain or w/e) to everything, the best solution is simply to use it whenever it is necessary.

In our site we use markup language to get HTML output from i18n locale files, since who translates those files are not developers, just translators.

If it is only on a few places that you need your HTML to really be HTML, use .html_safe

```
t('views.signup.organisation_details').html_safe
```

The simple markup language we have works pretty well for us, but that is really case-specific :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the html_safe method that can be used in helpers?  I am not sure if I totally understand the problem here since I have never worked with I18n, but would it be possible to use a custom helper that determines if the characters should not be escaped and return "string".html_safe, and if it should be escaped, return "string".

Or possibly override the "t" helper and add your escaping logic conditions + .html_safe

Comment: I don't know enough about the problem myself (and the 'Rails Way') to know if this is a good plan or another road to ruin, but thanks for the thought... Might try it out and let you know how it goes.