# Prevent Ruby from changing & to &amp;?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to display some superscript and subscript characters in my webpage title.  I have a helper method that recognizes the pattern for a subscript or superscript, and converts it to &sub2; or ²

However, when it shows up in the rendered page's file, it shows up in the source code as:

```
&amp;sub2;
```

Which is not right.  I have it set up to be:

```
<% provide(:title, raw(format_title(@hash[:page_title]))) %>
```

But the raw is not working.  Any help is appreciated.

Method:

```
def format_title(name)
label = name
if label.match /(_[\d]+_)+|(~[\d]+~)+/
  label = label.gsub(/(_([\d]+)_)+/, '&sub\2;')
  label = label.gsub(/(~([\d]+)~)+/, '&sup\2;')
  label.html_safe
else
  name
end
```

end

I have even tried:

```
str.gsub(/&amp;/, '&')
```

but it gives back:

```
&amp;amp;sub2;
```

Comment: What's in your `format_title` method?

Comment: Is that a typo that `<% provide....` is missing a `=`? In `.erb` for the embedded ruby to visible we have to use `<%= provide...`, right?

Comment: added method @NicNilov

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with Rails I18n.

```
<%= t(:page_title_html, scope: [:title]) %>
```

And in your respective locale file. (`title.en.yml` most probably):

```
title:
  page_title: "Title with &sup2;"
```

Here is a chart for [HTML symbols](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html#super) regarding subscript and superscripts.

For more information check [Preventing HTML character entities in locale files from getting munged by Rails3 xss protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477522/preventing-html-character-entities-in-locale-files-from-getting-munged-by-rails3)

---

**Update**:

In case you need to load the page titles dynamically, first, you'll have to install a gem like [Page Title Helper](https://github.com/lwe/page_title_helper).

You can follow the guide in the gem documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work for me, since the page title changes dynamically, depending on the page you are on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two of issues with your example, one is of matter and the other is just a coincidence.

The first issue is you are trying to use character entities that do not actually exist. Specifically, there are only `&sup1;`, `&sup2;` and `&sup3;` which provide <sup>1</sup>, <sup>2</sup> and <sup>3</sup> superscript symbols respectively. There is no such character entity as `&sup4;` nor any other superscript digits. There are though bare codepoints for other digits which you can use but this would require a more involved code.

More importantly, there are no subscript character entities at all in [HTML5 character entities list](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). All subscript digits are bare codepoints. Therefore it makes no sense to replace anything with `&sub2;` or any other "subscript" digit.

The reason you didn't see your example working is due to the test string you chose. Supplying anything with underscores, like `_2_mystring` will be properly replaced with `&sub2;`. As `&sub2;` character entity is non-existent, the string will appear as is, creating an impression that `raw` method somehow doesn't work.

Try to use `~2~mystring` and it will be replaced with the superscript character entity `&sup2;` and will be rendered correctly. This illustrates that your code correct, but the basic assumption about character entities is not.

Comment: Adding <sub></sub> tags will not help me, since this value needs to appear between the <title></title> tags.